# Best way to model identifiable has many?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I’m trying to figure out the best way to model a relationship. I have three tables: `Units`, `UnitCrews`, and `Users`.

Conceptually a Unit has a Crew consisting of 2+ Users in various positions; one Incharge, one Attendant, and zero or more Observers.

So a `Unit` should have one `UnitCrew`, and a `UnitCrew` should have many `Users`, but I need to know the position of each user.

If a `User` belongs to a `UnitCrew`, the fk would be on `UnitCrews`, but that would just add a `User_Id` column with no way to identify the position.

Ideally the `UnitCrews` table would have columns for `Incharge`, `Attendant`, and some way to identify 0+ `Observers`, but I’m not sure how that would work.

My initial thought is to create an additional table called `CrewAssignments` as a sort of join table, with a column `Type` whose value would be either `Incharge`, `Attendant`, or `Observer`. That would allow a `UnitCrew` to have many `CrewAssignments`, and a `User` to have one `CrewAssignment`.

Is the `CrewAssignments` table the best way to model this, or is there a better option?

---

**Edit**

Adding some clarification...

A `User` belongs to one `UnitCrew`, and a `UnitCrew` has many `Users`.

To better describe what I'm trying to achieve, here's the scenario I'm trying to model:

> Each Unit is staffed with a Crew. A Crew needs an Incharge, an Attendant, and can have zero or more Observers. Each position in the Crew (Incharge, Attendant, Observer) is a Crew Member. So a Crew Member is part of a (belongs to one) Crew as it's Incharge, Attendant, or Observer; and a Crew has many Crew Members.

In that scenario Unit = `Units`, Crew = `UnitCrews`, and Crew Member = `Users`

Comment: Please help me understand. Why not add the 'type' column aswell as the foreign key 'user_id' to the UnitCrews table?

Comment: Each `UnitCrew` has many `Users`. Adding a `type` column would help identify the position, but that leaves me trying to describe multiple has one relationships to the `Users` table. (i.e. “`UnitCrews` has one `Users` as `Incharge`“, “`UnitCrews` has one `Users` as `Attendant`”, and no way to add `Observers`)

Comment: There seem to be a many-to-many relationship between UnitCrews and Users, and in the pivot table (named for ex UnitCrewsUsers) you put 3 columns: isInCharge, isAttendant, isObserver. Also you add 2 unique constraints in the pivot table: UnitCrewId+isInCharge where true, UnitCrewId+isAttendant where true.

Comment: For me it looks like `UnitCrew` is already `many-to-many` junction table. I would just add foreign keys for `InCharge` and `Attendant` right in `Unit` and all observers (or other multiple users with different roles) should be records in `UnitCrew` with something like `type` column

Comment: Is a user assigned to only one crew or many crews ? In the second case, does the position  of a user vary depending on its crew assignments or is it linked to the user only and the same for all his assignments ?

Comment: For clarification, a 'User' belongs to one `UnitCrew`, but a `UnitCrew` has many `Users`. My trouble is being able to identify the position. I'll edit my question to show what I'd *like* to see, although I'm not sure if it's possible.